# How can I specify an alternate config file for a WCF client?

Tags: wcf, configuration-files, wcf-client

I am working on a large system, for which I have to use WCF to access a web service.  My test code works fine, now I need to integrate my WCF client code into the larger system.  I cannot add to the existing 'app.config' file, and would like specify a separate .config file for use by my client code.

How best can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 2 options.

**Option 1.  Working with channels.**

If you are working with channels directly, .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5 has the [ConfigurationChannelFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd575311%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  The example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee960149%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) looks like this:

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "Test.config";
Configuration newConfiguration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(
    fileMap,
    ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

ConfigurationChannelFactory<ICalculatorChannel> factory1 = 
    new ConfigurationChannelFactory<ICalculatorChannel>(
        "endpoint1", 
        newConfiguration, 
        new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8000/servicemodelsamples/service"));
ICalculatorChannel client1 = factory1.CreateChannel();
```

As pointed out by Langdon, you can use the endpoint address from the configuration file by simply passing in null, like this:

```
var factory1 = new ConfigurationChannelFactory<ICalculatorChannel>(
        "endpoint1", 
        newConfiguration, 
        null);
ICalculatorChannel client1 = factory1.CreateChannel();
```

This is discussed in the MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd575430.aspx).

**Option 2.  Working with proxies.**

If you're working with code-generated proxies, you can read the config file and load a [ServiceModelSectionGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.servicemodelsectiongroup.aspx).  There is a bit more work involved than simply using the `ConfigurationChannelFactory` but at least you can continue using the generated proxy (that under the hood uses a `ChannelFactory` and manages the `IChannelFactory` for you.

Pablo Cibraro shows a nice example of this here: [Getting WCF Bindings and Behaviors from any config source](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2010/05/11/getting-wcf-bindings-and-behaviors-from-any-config-source.aspx)

Comment: Philippe - I found Option 1 rather easy to use, but could you advice something more on Option2. All what I've found is number of unsupported @generators@ that are using Reflection, and don't cover 100% of possible configuration options.

Comment: @GeorgySmirnov, did you see the link to http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2010/05/11/getting-wcf-bindings-and-behaviors-from-any-config-source.aspx in option 2?  It shows a very good example.

Comment: Option 1 is sweet -- too bad ConfigurationChannelFactory's Dispose method is just as broken as ChannelFactory's, only this time the class is sealed so you can't extend it to make a sane version.

Answer (score 5):

you can't do this as you like - you can come close, but can't do it totally.

What you could do is add this section to the main app's config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <bindings configSource="bindings.config" />
   <behaviors configSource="behaviors.config" />
   <client configSource="client.config" />
   <services configSource="services.config" />
  .....
</system.serviceModel>
```

So for each section inside `<system.serviceModel>`, you could specify an external config file by using the `configSource=` attribute (and don't let Visual Studio's red squiggly lines confuse it - yes, it **DOES** work!).

You can do this for any configuration **section** - but unfortunately, there's no way to do this for the whole **section group** (`<system.serviceModel>`).

Marc

Comment: aye this is perfect!  I was doing this for connectionStrings for some environment CI/CD purposes for some legacy apps.  didn't know this applies to other sections.  I wish more supported "file=" for external files zz

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in support for this in WCF unfortunately. You must create your own ChannelFactory subclass and load/parse configuration files yourself. Check out [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/f33e620a-e332-4fd4-ae21-88c750437355/) here on MSDN forums for more implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can do it a simple and easy way - and implement a custom config file as in this post, which uses a DataSet / DataTable model to store / retrieve your configuration (includes working code):

[(.Net) suggestions on making a config file for a program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583673/net-suggestions-on-making-a-config-file-for-a-program/1583684#1583684)

Answer (score 0):

So the option mentioned by marc_s **DOES** work. Ignore Visual Studio warning that it doesn't recognize the configSource property on bindings and all other places.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for your post! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)